# What is it called when you have a procedure made of other procedures?

Tags: operating-system, programming-languages

This is a somewhat general question about the architecture of programming languages and software.

I'm working on a human operating system and I'm using terminology from software development to talk about various "functions" and "procedures" that could be applicable to human behavior.

The question is: what do you usually call a procedure, which is made from other procedures when you're talking about programming languages or software?

Comment: I don't think there's a specific term for a procedure that calls other procedures, but a general term for that architecture would be _procedural programming_

Comment: What do you mean `made of other procedures`? I think you may be thinking of `leaf` vs `non-leaf` procedures.

Comment: A procedure that calls other procedures in order to break a task in to smaller isolated parts is an example of [Functional Decomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947874/what-is-functional-decomposition).

Comment: I would call it 'normal'....?

Answer (score 1):

A **leaf function** is a function which doesn't call any other functions.

A **non-leaf function** is a function which calls at least one other function.